# In VS Code, is there a way to open all files that have merge conflicts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there a way to open all files that have merge conflicts?  When I have Git merge conflicts, I have to manually go find those files inthe project explorer.  I'd like to click some button that makes finding these conflicts easier.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "source control" button shows you all files with source control notes.

[image: Source control icon (with a "29 items" badge)]

In the source control section, there is list of files with merge conflicts. The files with merge conflicts have a C on the right side.

[image: Source control panel with merge conflicts]

Comment: Here it shows nothing, but clicking on some files does show some conflicts

Comment: Don't know why this is chosen as the selected answer, as the Source Control section in VSCode does not specifically have a place that shows all files with merge conflicts.

Comment: @TerranRich I have updated the answer to provide a screenshot of where conflicts are represented.

Comment: After running `git merge` in the terminal, the changes finally show up in vscode! And one can then even use the merge editor to resolve them = )

Answer (score 2):

Use the Search feature in VS Code (Ctrl+Shift+F) and search the repo for `<<<<<<< HEAD`.

Comment: This is a far more useful answer than the accepted answer :-)